# How to get like posts status without reload or refresh page in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a dynamic list of posts. In each post, I added a "like" and a "comment" button. My problem is that when I click on the like button I have to reload the page manually for changes to show.

One solution I thought of was adding an API call to the like button's `(click)` event so that it reloads the page, but this isn't looking good.

page.html

```html
    <ion-col *ngIf="feed.IsLike" tappable>
        <ion-icon (click)="toggleLikeState(feed.UserId, feed.PostId);$event.stopPropagation();" tappable
            name="heart"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span *ngIf="feed.LikesCount > 0">{{feed.LikesCount}}</span>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col *ngIf="!feed.IsLike" tappable>
        <ion-icon (click)="toggleLikeState(feed.UserId, feed.PostId);$event.stopPropagation();" tappable
            name="heart-empty"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span *ngIf="feed.LikesCount > 0">{{feed.LikesCount}}</span>
    </ion-col>
```

page.ts

```js
    toggleLikeState(UserId: number, PostId: number) {
    this.storage.get('userID').then(async (loggedinUId) => {
      const value: {
        LoginUserId: string,
        UserId: number,
        PostId: number
      } = {
        LoginUserId: loggedinUId,
        UserId: UserId,
        PostId: PostId
      };
      this.apiService.postLike(value).then(async (success) => {
        console.log("succ", success);
        if (success = 0) {
          console.log(success);
          this.IsLike = !this.IsLike;
          this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
            this.feedlist = data;
          });
          if (this.IsLike) {
            this.iconName = 'heart';
          } else {
            this.iconName = 'heart-empty';
          }
        } else {
          this.IsLike = !this.IsLike;
          this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
            this.feedlist = data;
          });
          if (this.IsLike) {
            this.iconName = 'heart';
          } else {
            this.iconName = 'heart-empty';
          }
        }
      }, error => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
    });
    }

Here my code, is there any way to display like's without reloading the page or I have to user socket.io?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters you can improve the HTML view by using a ternary operator instead of the *ngIf directive. You would apply this only on the icon's name since the rest of the markup is going to remain in both scenarios.

`{{ condition? 'conditionWasTrue' : 'conditionWasFalse' }}` is a good way to write an if-else in a single line, then your HTML code would look like this:

```html
<ion-col tappable>
    <ion-icon (click)="toggleLikeState(feed.UserId,feed.PostId);$event.stopPropagation();" 
              tappable name="{{feed.IsLike ? 'heart' : 'heart-empty'}}">
    </ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span *ngIf="feed.LikesCount > 0">{{feed.LikesCount}}</span>
</ion-col>
```

Then in your typeScript file, you won't need the "iconName" variable anymore, so you can erase a good part of it and it'll start looking cleaner. Even better, you can move the interface declaration outside of the function's scope:

**EDIT:** If you want to update the number of likes without refreshing the view you'll need to return the new number of likes during the response of your `apiService.postLike()` method.

After updating your backend API to include the new LikesCount when postLike() is successful, you can use the new `response.LikesCount` property to update the component's internal variables:

```js
interface UserLikedPost {
    LoginUserId: string,
    UserId: number,
    PostId: number
}

toggleLikeState(UserId: number, PostId: number) {
  this.storage.get('userID').then(async (loggedinUId) => {
    const value: UserLikedPost = {
      LoginUserId: loggedinUId,
      UserId: UserId,
      PostId: PostId
    };

    this.apiService.postLike(value).then(
      async (success) => {
        console.log("succ", success);
        this.IsLike = !this.IsLike;
        this.feed.LikesCount = success.LikesCount; // Here is where you update your likes without refreshing. 
        this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
          this.feedlist = data;
        });
      }, (error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  });
}
```

Every time you want to update a screen's view with new information, then you'll need to perform an API call, but it doesn't need to look that bad. Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to display data without refresh

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry. You can update `feed.LikesCount` during the success callback, I'll update my answer.

Comment: This way working good for single post page but I have a list of multiple posts and as I said in question each post have like button. what to do for loop?

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but it's difficult to help without the code that's making that happen. I mean, the one with the `*ngFor` and the list. Since this part of the problem (About not refreshing the page) has been solved, can we make a new question about the `*ngFor` iteration problem? Pass the link of the new question here and I'll be glad to help you with that issue as well :)